# I cant go to bios ideapad slim 3

Tags: bios, grub

I have tried to press f2 and all of thos keys. I cant go to bios. Even the novo button doesn't work. I have been trying from yesterday. Fast boot is disabled. I dont have any os on it. I can access then grub commandline. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Get it running, and then restart.   As soon as the restart begins, press F1 (or F2) repeatedly and see if that launches BIOS.

Comment: I have tried but it just gets stuck at the logo

Comment: You probably should call Lenovo Support at this point.

Comment: true, tho is there anyway to disable fast startup with "initramfs"?

Comment: I don't think so but I do not know for sure.

Comment: Why didn't i just watch a video instead of spending 2 days on trying to fix my computer.